# Reorder repeater controller rows in asp.net with Foreign key with C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

i want to write commenting section for my personal website and i want users could be replay to specific comment as they want.. and the replay must be below that comment they answered. 
I use repeater controller and this is my code:

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="rptComments" runat="server" OnItemCommand="rptComments_ItemCommand">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <div class="media comment text-right" runat="server" visible='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("CommentIsReplay")) == false %>'>
                        <div class="media-body">
                            <h4>
                                <asp:Literal ID="lblCommentAuthorName" Text='<%# Eval("CommentAuthorName") %>' runat="server"></asp:Literal></h4>
                            <span>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblCommentDate_FA" Text='<%# Eval("CommentDate_FA") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label></span>
                            <p>
                                <asp:Literal ID="lblCOmmentText" Text='<%# Eval("COmmentText") %>' runat="server"></asp:Literal>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="media-bottom clearfix">
                            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server"
                                Text="Replay"
                                CommandName="getCommentCode"
                                CommandArgument='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"CommentCode") %>'
                                CssClass="btn btn-default pull-left" Style="max-width: 20%;" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="media comment text-right commentReplay" runat="server" visible='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("CommentIsReplay")) == true %>'>
                        <div class="media-body">
                            <h4>
                                <asp:Literal ID="Literal1" Text='<%# Eval("CommentAuthorName") %>' runat="server"></asp:Literal></h4>

                            <p>
                                <asp:Literal ID="Literal2" Text='<%# Eval("COmmentText") %>' runat="server"></asp:Literal>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="media-bottom clearfix">
                            <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server"
                                Text="Replay"
                                CommandName="getCommentCode"
                                CommandArgument='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"CommentCode") %>'
                                CssClass="btn btn-default pull-left" Style="max-width: 20%;" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </ItemTemplate>
```

As you can see, I wrote 2 section and check the rows to know what comment is replay type and who is not..
I Store the Comment Code For replay and one field to check if that are replay or not...

My qusetion is how i could reorder the rows with this code.
Thanks

Comment: are you binding this repeater to a datatable?

Comment: @Mysterio11 dataTable ?

Comment: where is your data coming from

Comment: @Mysterio11 the data will be displayed right now, and i have no question about that...
i want to reAlign or reorder the rows

Comment: im asking about the data because i normally re order the data before binding it to the repeater. for example after a reply is posted i reorder the data according to time of posting in descending order and then bind it to the repeater

Comment: @Mysterio11 do you think its okey ? for example, if one of my users posted a comment right now, and another one want to replay that comment 2days later.. and another users posted comment today, how time order works?

Comment: im really sorry i misunderstood your question. you want the reply to come under the comment right? i thought you wanted the comment to come on top

Comment: this is the solution i had implemented. first i used a datalist and used another datalist inside it(my guess is repeater should work just as well). My table ad a column called parent commentid. if this was zero then its a fresh comment or if someone replied to a comment this would be saved with the original comments id in the parrent comment id. then in the itemdatabound event for the outer datalist iwould query the db for all comments with the id of the current comment in the parent commentid field and bind it to the inner datalist

Comment: @Mysterio11 oh, thank you. let me try nested repeaters

Comment: table structure :Id,Text,commenttime,Parentcommentid.
Normal comment: 1,"Hello how are you?","5/1/2015 7:56:00PM",0
Reply to comment with id 1: 2,"I am fine","5/1/2015 7:58:00PM",1

Comment: did it work?? can you implement nested repeaters?

Comment: @Mysterio11 check my answer. Thanks

Comment: Ill post this as answer please mark it as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the solution i had implemented. first i used a datalist and used another datalist inside it(my guess is repeater should work just as well). My table ad a column called parent commentid. if this was zero then its a fresh comment or if someone replied to a comment this would be saved with the original comments id in the parrent comment id. then in the itemdatabound event for the outer datalist iwould query the db for all comments with the id of the current comment in the parent commentid field and bind it to the inner datalist –

Answer (score 1):

so, I implemented nested repeaters and it's works well.  here you can check the code...

The main Repeater retrive the data from Comments Table with Post foreign key. the second repeater check the table to find is the parent id has any childern ? and its work with OnItemDataBound.

```
 <asp:repeater id="rptComments" runat="server" onitemcommand="rptComments_ItemCommand" onitemdatabound="rptComments_ItemDataBound">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <div class="media comment text-right" runat="server" >
                        <div class="media-body">
                            <h4>
                                <asp:Literal ID="lblCommentAuthorName" Text='<%# Eval("CommentAuthorName") %>' runat="server"></asp:Literal></h4>
                            <span>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblCommentDate_FA" Text='<%# Eval("CommentDate_FA") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label></span>
                            <p>
                                <asp:Literal ID="lblCOmmentText" Text='<%# Eval("COmmentText") %>' runat="server"></asp:Literal>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="media-bottom clearfix">
                            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server"
                                Text="Replay"
                                CommandName="getCommentCode"
                                CommandArgument='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"CommentCode") %>'
                                CssClass="btn btn-default pull-left" Style="max-width: 20%;" />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <asp:Repeater ID="rptReplay" runat="server" onitemcommand="rptComments_ItemCommand">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <div class="media comment text-right commentReplay" runat="server">
                                <div class="media-body">
                                    <h4>
                                        <asp:Literal ID="Literal1" Text='<%# Eval("CommentAuthorName") %>' runat="server"></asp:Literal></h4>
                                     <span>
                                <asp:Label ID="Label1" Text='<%# Eval("CommentDate_FA") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label></span>

                                    <p>
                                        <asp:Literal ID="Literal2" Text='<%# Eval("COmmentText") %>' runat="server"></asp:Literal>
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="media-bottom clearfix">
                                    <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server"
                                        Text="Replay"
                                        CommandName="getCommentCodeParent"
                                        CommandArgument='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"CommentCode") %>'
                                        CssClass="btn btn-default pull-left" Style="max-width: 20%;" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:Repeater>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:repeater>
```

and code behind:

```
    protected void rptComments_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        TblComment item = (TblComment)(e.Item.DataItem);
        Int32 code = Convert.ToInt32(item.CommentCode);


        var replay = (from a in db.TblComments
                      where a.CommentReplayTo == code && a.CommentIsReplay == true && a.CommentIsApprove == true
                      select a).ToList();



        Repeater rptReplay = (Repeater)e.Item.FindControl("rptReplay");
        rptReplay.DataSource = replay;
        rptReplay.DataBind();
       }
}
```

i hope it helps someone in future..
thanks